# Parsing an image with JAI

Tags: java

I use JAI, because I want to work with a tif. I read the image into a PlanarImage

The whole problem:
Now I have to do some calculations on this image. First I have to read the RGB values, then do some calculations on blocks with 16x16 pixels.

What's the best way to do this?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What kind of calculations are you doing?  It's possible that there's already a filter or operation class for your purpose.  Especially if it can be represented by a color transformation or 16x16 convolution operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this for easy access is a two-dimensional array.